# Open two dropdowns with the same function in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, drop-down-menu, react-hooks

I have two `dropdown` menus, one to choose the `columns` of my `Table` and another one to choose a `filter` for this `column`.
Actually I have two functions to open both of `dropdowns` (one function per `dropdown`) and I would like to have just one function for both of them.
It maybe simple, but I don't know how to do it.. if someone had the solution, it would be great.

My state:

```
const [anchorEl, setAnchorEl] = React.useState({
  column: null,
  filter: null
});
```

The two functions for the two `dropdowns`:

```
const handleClickDropdownColumn = (event) => {
  setAnchorEl({
    column: event.currentTarget,
  });
};
const handleClickDropdownFilter = (event) => {
  setAnchorEl({
    filter: event.currentTarget,
  });
};
```

And the two `buttons` for open the two `dropdowns`:

```
<Button
  variant="contained"
  size="small"
  aria-controls="simple-menu"
  aria-haspopup="true"
  onClick={handleClickDropdownColumn}
  endIcon={<ArrowDropDownIcon/>}
>
  {currentColumn}
</Button>
```

```
<IconButton onClick={handleClickDropdownFilter}>
  {currentFilter}
</IconButton>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Method 1: Pass in your name as second argument to your function handler

You can write your `onClick` props as the following,

```
<Button
  variant="contained"
  size="small"
  aria-controls="simple-menu"
  aria-haspopup="true"
  onClick={e => handleClickDropdown(e, 'column')}
  endIcon={<ArrowDropDownIcon/>}
>
  {currentColumn}
</Button>

<IconButton onClick={e => handleClickDropdown(e, 'filter')}>
  {currentFilter}
</IconButton>
```

Then in your handler

```js
const handleClickDropdown = (event, name) => {
    setAnchorEl({
        [name]: event.currentTarget,
    });
};
```

### Method 2: Function that returns a function handler

```
<Button
  variant="contained"
  size="small"
  aria-controls="simple-menu"
  aria-haspopup="true"
  onClick={handleClickDropdown('column')}
  endIcon={<ArrowDropDownIcon/>}
>
  {currentColumn}
</Button>

<IconButton onClick={handleClickDropdown('filter')}>
  {currentFilter}
</IconButton>
```

In your handler, you call a function with `name` and returns a handler for that property.

```js
const handleClickDropdown = (name) => (event) => {
    setAnchorEl({
        [name]: event.currentTarget,
    });
};
```

Comment: Super, thanks a lot @dev_junwen ! Your solution has unlocked me on a number of cases :)

Answer (score 0):

You could set your handler function to this and use it for both buttons.

```
const handleClickDropdown = (event, type) => {
  if(type in anchorEl){
    setAnchorEl({
      ...anchorEl,
      [type]: event.currentTarget,
      })
  }
}
```

Comment: You shouldn't spread your `anchorEl` after your `[type]: event.currentTarget` else your new value is going to get overwritten again.

Comment: Tnx for spotting my error, However setAnchorEl replaces the state, thus spreading the state first then using computed property does a merge